# flex / c++ regex logic error

Tags: c++, regex, flex-lexer

I did my best to include all of (and only) the information that is needed. Let me know if seeing more could help you help me.

I am having problems with my regex. My program prints to a .txt file lexeme - token pairs. Everything is working fine except for identifiers and integers. For example, the token for an identifier is 262.

Sample input file:

```
function main a: integer returns integer;
    b: integer is a * 2;
```

Sample output:

```
function - 269
maina - 262
integer - 272
returns - 274
integer - 272
; - 59
b - 262
integer - 272
is - 271
a - 262
2 - 263
; - 59
```

Correct output would be:

```
function - 269
main - 262
a - 262
: - 58
integer - 272
returns - 274
integer - 272
; - 59
b - 262
: - 58
integer - 272
is - 271
a - 262
* - 261
2 - 263
; - 59
```

To summarize, it combines two identifiers separated by a white space, and it also deletes any token after the identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just forgotten to put curly braces around some of the names. Instead of

```
{letter}(letter|digit)*
```

you should write

```
{letter}({letter}|{digit})*
```

You also need to move the rules for **function**, **integer** and **returns** before the rule for identifier, since the rule for identifier match those too.

Comment: Your comment on putting the keywords before the identifier was helpful, but bracing off the names didn't change the output problems.

Comment: Nevermind. I switched back to my old function using your regex corrections and it worked. Thanks!